# Can you assign multiple Params in a variable in a .env file?

Tags: node.js, variables, parameters, dotenv

I want to create a new variable and use 2 parameters in it. How can I do that? I have newPerson as the variable. The variable should contain a userid and password. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this cannot be done in an env file.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. In a .env file every entry will be parse to a string. In most languages, including JavaScript, you can use a method to change the string to other type, like JSON.parse to get an object or an array. A common use would be:

```
let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(process.env.SOME_COMPLEX_DATA));
```